# What can I conclude from the following Granger causality test?

Tags: r, time-series, granger-causality

I have two monthly time series:

- one for house prices expressed in annual change growth rates: $\left( \text{ln}(X_t) - \text{ln}(X_{t-12})\right) - \left( \text{ln}(X_{t-1}) - \text{ln}(X_{t-1-12})\right)$;
- the other simply in growth rates: $\text{ln}(X_t) - \text{ln}(X_{t-1})$.

Here is the data:

```
House Prices = [1]  0.009189829  0.022612618  0.003952796 -0.015179184  0.001903336 -0.028779902  0.025668239 -0.011237850
  [9]  0.014782630 -0.018844480 -0.023547458  0.020613233  0.029281069 -0.010539781  0.006707366  0.023693144
 [17] -0.002632498  0.148738752 -0.154539337  0.013908319 -0.002294980  0.013274177  0.010043605 -0.007862785
 [25] -0.018297295 -0.003167249  0.022984841  0.001666694 -0.001310199 -0.131548705  0.114723242 -0.003431495
 [33]  0.000953231 -0.010096108 -0.009434595 -0.037774255  0.030877947 -0.011245971 -0.018800312 -0.012805013
 [41]  0.001326392 -0.012034079 -0.045279346 -0.017308170  0.002490863 -0.007340975  0.005052948 -0.024053201
 [49] -0.004190424 -0.028607790  0.004678486  0.026626293 -0.015166864  0.006988983  0.038257855  0.020798177
 [57]  0.008175391  0.021294030 -0.013331432  0.030969145  0.017065249 -0.002672683  0.019435476 -0.037047871
 [65]  0.001844432  0.007663458  0.034406137 -0.049379845 -0.012527106 -0.012859680  0.012954488 -0.015463951
 [73] -0.025509006  0.006318645  0.012977464  0.019940525 -0.025592828  0.020774198 -0.033613414  0.018338077
 [81]  0.001765807  0.009236604 -0.041413104  0.030227358  0.017180849  0.012593360 -0.039001526 -0.004994992
 [89]  0.037766071 -0.043167230 -0.016613786  0.023199890 -0.016214873 -0.012282560  0.065978520 -0.031465767
 [97]  0.006355108 -0.000449523 -0.005810647  0.016823517 -0.021988463  0.026178014  0.007654339 -0.008356379
[105]  0.013273736  0.031645473 -0.046408064  0.022334664  0.008517194 -0.014892335  0.019147342  0.007955040
[113]  0.014122506 -0.035722162  0.018174284  0.021410306 -0.038943797 -0.014517888  0.032750195  0.022506553
[121] -0.003870785  0.130924075 -0.057934974 -0.174228244  0.016937619  0.010647759  0.015691962 -0.033174094
[129]  0.038263205  0.003456250 -0.013422897

B = [1] -0.0223848461  0.0102749646  0.0913403867 -0.0758207770 -0.0053898407 -0.0204047336  0.0050358986
  [8]  0.0195335195 -0.0200303353 -0.0045390828  0.0056380761 -0.0004492945  0.0040043649  0.0012918928
 [15] -0.0104850394  0.0047110190  0.0049805985 -0.0046957178  0.0095002549  0.0202597343 -0.0183526932
 [22]  0.0237185217 -0.0137022065  0.0133787918 -0.0212629487  0.0070512978  0.0959447868 -0.0801519036
 [29] -0.0362526334 -0.0000278572  0.0269014993  0.0009862920 -0.0329868357  0.0283667004 -0.0135186142
 [36] -0.0004975495  0.0053822189  0.0108219907 -0.0078419784  0.0418340658 -0.0316367599 -0.0092324801
 [43] -0.0192830637  0.0336003682  0.0021479539 -0.0146426306  0.0003717930  0.0216259502 -0.0323127786
 [50]  0.0033077606 -0.0123735085 -0.0014757035  0.0266339779 -0.0228959378  0.0002848944  0.0133572802
 [57] -0.0093035312 -0.0034350607  0.0052349772  0.0115210916 -0.0122443122  0.0435497970 -0.0100099291
 [64]  0.0267252321 -0.0654005679  0.0088385287 -0.0089122237  0.0155299273 -0.0027394997 -0.0126183268
 [71]  0.0090999709  0.0017039487 -0.0144843611  0.0269128625  0.0042663583  0.0220574344 -0.0523831016
 [78] -0.0059331639  0.0171559908  0.0125030653  0.0151902738  0.0471484001 -0.0477394702  0.0888317354
 [85] -0.1044700154  0.0234134906 -0.0215966718  0.0157974035  0.0970094980 -0.1049559862 -0.0290578406
 [92]  0.0617653831 -0.0132202439  0.0022117274  0.0091225692  0.0424813190 -0.0614889434  0.0163745828
 [99] -0.0112793057  0.0666179349 -0.0352838073 -0.0259179501  0.0269557599  0.0127882202 -0.0430512536
[106]  0.0862308560 -0.0633012329  0.0596481270  0.0900367605 -0.0303162498 -0.0153738373 -0.0442218848
[113] -0.0116158350 -0.0531058308  0.2036373944  0.1598602057 -0.3837940703 -0.0069112146 -0.0192015196
[120]  0.0110269191 -0.0351135484  0.0439917033  0.0522746614  0.0036354828 -0.0414276671 -0.0361649669
[127]  0.0080753079  0.0352684982 -0.0282391428 -0.0141622744  0.0045799464
```

I am studying if `B` has an effect on `House prices`. For this reason first a take a simple liner regression between the two and I get a negative and significant estimate at the 95% confidence interval: (-0.0004189 *).

Wanting to reach a step forward I undertake a Granger causality test as following:

I) Determine the optimal number of lags using the AIC/BIC test using:

```
select.lags<-function(x,y,max.lag=20) {
  y<-as.numeric(y)
  y.lag<-embed(y,max.lag+1)[,-1,drop=FALSE]
  x.lag<-embed(x,max.lag+1)[,-1,drop=FALSE]

  t<-tail(seq_along(y),nrow(y.lag))

  ms=lapply(1:max.lag,function(i) lm(y[t]~y.lag[,1:i]+x.lag[,1:i]))

  pvals<-mapply(function(i) anova(ms[[i]],ms[[i-1]])[2,"Pr(>F)"],max.lag:2)
  ind<-which(pvals<0.05)[1]
  ftest<-ifelse(is.na(ind),1,max.lag-ind+1)

  aic<-as.numeric(lapply(ms,AIC))
  bic<-as.numeric(lapply(ms,BIC))
  structure(list(ic=cbind(aic=aic,bic=bic),pvals=pvals,
                 selection=list(aic=which.min(aic),bic=which.min(bic),ftest=ftest)))
}

s<-select.lags(Topic.15,House.Prices,20)
t(s$selection)
plot.ts(s$ic)
```

As a result I get:

```
aic bic ftest
14  12  13
```

Here is when it comes the first doubt: why are they giving me different results? Nevertheless, when I do the Granger causality test for both directions using these numbers as possible lags I get in all high significant results (***) only in the direction that `B` is causing `House prices` movements:

```
lmtest::grangertest(Topic.15,House.Prices,12)
lmtest::grangertest(House.Prices,Topic.15,12)
```

I do not seem to see the direction of the cause, is it possitive or negative (an increase in `B` produces an increase or a drop in `House prices` at time $t+1$?).
Another question, is the conclusion valid that changes in `B` produce changes in `House prices`? What are the weakness in this line of argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why are they giving me different results?

Why should they *not* give you different results? AIC and BIC are not the same. They serve different goals and are optimal in different ways (e.g. AIC is efficient while BIC is consistent). If you want to use the model for prediction, you could prefer AIC due to its efficiency. For explanatory modelling, BIC could be chosen for its consistency.

In any case, the models are quite large for a sample size of mere 131 observation. Since you could expect monthly seasonality here, consider using just the first few lags plus the lag number 12, or seasonally adjust the data in advance and rerun the lag order selection. **Edit** Responding to a relevant comment: Since you used seasonal differencing when constructing the `Housing price` time series, there is probably no need to look for seasonality there.

> I do not seem to see the direction of the cause, is it possitive or negative (and increase in B produces an increase or a drop in House prices at t+1?)

Take a look at impulse response functions (IRFs). Consider a positive impulse to `B` and see how `House prices` react over time. You could do that using "vars" package in R. Select model order (may do it manually or use function `VARselect`), estimate the model (function `VAR`) and extract impulse responses (function `irf`).

> is the conclusion valid that changes in B produce changes in House prices? what are the weakness in this line of argument?

If you conclude that `B` Granger-causes `House prices`, the model must have shown (with, say, 95% confidence) that indeed changes in `B` produce changes in `House prices`. If you believe the model is alright and there are no hidden problems (e.g. there is no hidden factor that causes both `B` and `House prices`), the argument is fine.

Note: I did not proof-read your code but I assume it does what you say it does.

Comment: Great answer @Richard, thanks a lot! since House prices are computed as the the first difference in the annual change of each observations which after computing the acf() showed no seasonality this should not be a problem right. Also, variable B has no seasonality nor trend.

Comment: Oh, I did not take the time to think about that. Indeed, seasonal differencing (as you appear to be doing) should remove seasonality. But why then does AIC and BIC suggest such a high lag order for such a small sample?.. You could double check by using `VARselect`, perhaps there is a mistake in your code.

Comment: By the way, any idea on how to code the positive impulse to B and its reaction to House prices through impulse response functions in R?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Are you having a difficulty using the `irf` function, or do you want to do the analysis by hand? If the latter, forecast from the model a few steps ahead using $\varepsilon_{t+1,B}=\sigma_B$ (one standard deviation) but all the other shocks to `B` and to `House price` equal to zero.